# Python 3. Selenium - how to use multiple conditions with find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I can't find a solution. The htlm code is as follows :

```
<select class="SelectEquipe2" name="Equipe2Id">
    <option value='2'>AC Ajaccio<option value='3'>GFC Ajaccio<option value='15'>Amiens SC<option value='19'>Angers SCO<option value='30'>...
</select>
```

The problem is that there is a `class="SelectEquipe1"` I can't select option value from the second class. I tried the following code on Python 3.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class,"SelectEquipe2"]/option[@value="15"]').click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[contains(@class,"SelectEquipe2") and contains(.,"15")]')
```

with no success...

do you have any solution?

EDIT :

The actual HTML code :

```
 <select class="SelectEquipe2" name="Equipe2Id">
 <option value='41'selected>AJ Auxerre<option value='47'>SC Bastia<option value='65'>FC Girondins de Bordeaux<option value='76'>Stade Brestois 29<option value='82'>SM Caen<option value='139'>Dijon FCO<option value='177'>EA Guingamp<option value='201'>Istres FC<option value='224'>Havre AC<option value='226'>Le Mans FC<option value='231'>RC Lens<option value='242'>Lille OSC<option value='251'>FC Lorient<option value='258'>Olympique Lyonnais<option value='275'>Olympique de Marseille<option value='285'>FC Metz<option value='290'>AS Monaco FC<option value='299'>Montpellier Hérault SC<option value='308'>AS Nancy Lorraine<option value='310'>FC Nantes<option value='314'>OGC Nice<option value='339'>Paris Saint-Germain FC<option value='373'>Stade de Reims<option value='375'>Stade Rennais FC<option value='398'>AS Saint-Etienne<option value='429'>CS Sedan<option value='439'>FC Sochaux-Montbéliard<option value='442'>RC Strasbourg Alsace<option value='568'>Thonon Évian FC<option value='455'>Toulouse FC<option value='464'>ESTAC Troyes<option value='471'>Valenciennes FC       
 </select>
```

I succeed in selecting the option value for the first class "SelectEquipe1" using :

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="SelectEquipe1"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='339']").click()

but this does not work for the 2nd class, it always takes the first class options whereas I want it to take the second one.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have provided the actual _HTML_ within the question or provided a tailor made _HTML_?

Comment: That is the actual HTML from the code source, I did not just put all the option value but that's the structure

Answer (score 0):

After checking the *HTML* you have provided. It is clear that there is no closing tag for `<option>` tags. You will not be able to select the second option unless there is closing `</option>` tag for the first option.

Your html should look like this.

```
<select class="SelectEquipe2" name="Equipe2Id">
<option value='2'>AC Ajaccio</option><option value='3'>GFC Ajaccio</option><option value='15'>Amiens SC</option><option value='19'>Angers SCO</option><option value='30'></option>...
</select>
```

*All child nodes must be properly closed*

Answer (score 0):

The answer was merely to use :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='SelectEquipe2']/option[@value='258']").click()
```

thank you all